# Total number of solutions possible in the below function

Tags: calculus, functions

Consider $f(x)$ = $2^x - x^2 -1$ , how many solutions are in total there for f(x)= 0  ? My progress : since we do not need exact solutions so by hit and trial i find that one trivial solution occurs at $x = 0$ , for other solutions i considered the slope nature which tells that in 0 to 1 slope of $x^2+1$ is greater than $2^x$ so i thought there will be a solution at $x=1$ which is correct but is there any more ?

Comment: Clearer if you state that you are looking for zeros of the function, rather than "solutions".

Comment: Yeah sry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: here is the plot of the function. Can you prove that there are three solutions? Think of zeros of the derivative, maybe second derivative.
[image]

Comment: Second derivative tells 2^x (ln2)^2 = 2 this tells it has exactly one x satisfying it from the graph of 2^x , from there we can say first derivative would surely have two solutions and hence function would surely have three solutions ?

Comment: Finally yes. But you need to show that step by step. You need to show that there is a positive maximum at a lower $x$ value than a negative minimum. You also need to account for the sign of the function at $\pm\infty$. Since the function is continuous, if it changes sign in an interval, it will necessarily have a root in that interval.

Comment: Understood thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is a continuous function. The Intermediate Value Theorem can be your friend here.

Comment: Comments, like your good hint, would not be an answer.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash When I hover my mouse over comments (just below the original post) I see "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." This was neither a request for more information nor a suggestion of an improvement (although I did suggest an improvement separately in a comment). This was a hint, perhaps pointing toward an answer, as I might give a student who came to me asking for help on this exercise.

Comment: @paw88789 indeed IVT can help but then i would need to exactly figure out when the f(x) goes negative and how many times so that i am able to check roots in that ranges possible isnt ?

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer One should be able to get some sort of bounds on where the function is decreasing--its certainly increasing for negative numbers and for sufficiently large positive numbers. You can check concavity pretty easily (there is just one sign change in the second derivative). Hence there is not too much 'wiggle' in the graph, so there won't be lots of zeros.

Comment: Understood.....